# CASE WHEN in Order By taking too much time

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I have very weird behavior. If my query have,

```
,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CDF.Id) AS [ROW_Number]
```

Then it will take 1 to 2 seconds. If I have,

```
,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CASE '' WHEN '' THEN CDF.Id END) AS [ROW_Number]
```

Then it will take 1 to 2 seconds. But If I have a variable with empty value,

```
DECLARE @SortExpression varchar(50)=''
,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CASE @SortExpression WHEN '' THEN CDF.Id END) AS [ROW_Number]
```

Then it will take 12 to 16 seconds. In my real query I have some CASE statements CASE WHEN statements in ORDER BY clause. Here is my real query,

```
,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
                    ORDER BY 
                    CASE WHEN @SortExpression = 'MerchantName' THEN M.Name END ASC,
                    CASE WHEN @SortExpression = '-MerchantName' THEN M.Name END DESC,
                    CASE WHEN @SortExpression = 'Id' THEN CD.Id END ASC,
                    CASE WHEN @SortExpression = '-Id' THEN CD.Id END DESC,
                    CASE WHEN @SortExpression = 'MerchantProductId' THEN CD.MerchantProductId END ASC,
                    CASE WHEN @SortExpression = '-MerchantProductId' THEN CD.MerchantProductId END DESC,
                    CASE WHEN @SortExpression = 'Sku' THEN CD.Sku END ASC,
                    CASE WHEN @SortExpression = '-Sku' THEN CD.Sku END DESC,
                    CASE WHEN @SortExpression = 'ModelNumber' THEN CD.ModelNumber END ASC,
                    CASE WHEN @SortExpression = '-ModelNumber' THEN CD.ModelNumber END DESC,
                    CASE WHEN @SortExpression = 'Offer' THEN CD.Offer END ASC,
                    CASE WHEN @SortExpression = '-Offer' THEN CD.Offer END DESC,
                    CASE WHEN @SortExpression = 'Price' THEN CD.Price END ASC,
                    CASE WHEN @SortExpression = '-Price' THEN CD.Price END DESC,
                    CASE WHEN @SortExpression = 'NewPrice' THEN CD.NewPrice END ASC,
                    CASE WHEN @SortExpression = '-NewPrice' THEN CD.NewPrice END DESC,
                    CASE WHEN @SortExpression = 'InventoryControlType' THEN CD.InventoryControlType END ASC,
                    CASE WHEN @SortExpression = '-InventoryControlType' THEN CD.InventoryControlType END DESC,
                    CASE WHEN @SortExpression = 'Inventory' THEN CD.Inventory END ASC,
                    CASE WHEN @SortExpression = '-Inventory' THEN CD.Inventory END DESC,
                    CASE WHEN @SortExpression = 'Featured' THEN CD.Featured END ASC,
                    CASE WHEN @SortExpression = '-Featured' THEN CD.Featured END DESC,
                    CASE WHEN @SortExpression = 'Visible' THEN CD.Visible END ASC,
                    CASE WHEN @SortExpression = '-Visible' THEN CD.Visible END DESC,
                    CASE WHEN @SortExpression = 'Field1' THEN CD.Field1 END ASC,
                    CASE WHEN @SortExpression = '-Field1' THEN CD.Field1 END DESC,
                    CASE WHEN @SortExpression = 'Field2' THEN CD.Field2 END ASC,
                    CASE WHEN @SortExpression = '-Field2' THEN CD.Field2 END DESC,
                    CASE WHEN @SortExpression = 'Field3' THEN CD.Field3 END ASC,
                    CASE WHEN @SortExpression = '-Field3' THEN CD.Field3 END DESC,
                    CASE WHEN @SortExpression = 'Field4' THEN CD.Field4 END ASC,
                    CASE WHEN @SortExpression = '-Field4' THEN CD.Field4 END DESC,
                    CASE WHEN @SortExpression = 'OutletCode' THEN CD.OutletCode END ASC,
                    CASE WHEN @SortExpression = '-OutletCode' THEN CD.OutletCode END DESC,
                    CASE WHEN @SortExpression = 'Stock' THEN CD.Stock END ASC,
                    CASE WHEN @SortExpression = '-Stock' THEN CD.Stock END DESC,
                    CASE WHEN @SortExpression = 'Order' THEN CD.[Order] END ASC,
                    CASE WHEN @SortExpression = '-Order' THEN CD.[Order] END DESC,
                    CASE WHEN @SortExpression = 'ErrorDescription' THEN CD.[ErrorDescription] END ASC,
                    CASE WHEN @SortExpression = '-ErrorDescription' THEN CD.[ErrorDescription] END DESC,
                    CASE WHEN @SortExpression = 'CreationDateUtc' THEN CD.[CreationDateUtc] END ASC,
                    CASE WHEN @SortExpression = '-CreationDateUtc' THEN CD.[CreationDateUtc] END DESC,
                    CDF.Id, CD.[Order]
) AS [ROW_Number]
```

Comment: What is the difference in execution plans between the fast query and the slow one?

Comment: First of all, I would make that a single CASE with a bunch of WHENs instead of a bunch of CASEs

Comment: @TabAlleman can you gave an exaple how to rewrite the above(please note I have ASC and DESC)

Comment: @TabAlleman . . . That is a very bad idea.  The overall issue is probably the use of indexes.  I'm not sure if there is a way around it, other than by reducing the volume of data returned by the query.

Comment: having top 10 doesn't help, it has to sort everything to find the top 10

Comment: Oh my god. When we have such huge cases we do it in dynamic query. Building query and then it becomes lightweight.

Comment: The problem is not lot of CASES. This is happening with one CASE statement. The problem is that if I have ` @SortExpression = ''` and  @SortExpression is empty

Comment: @user960567, the problem is in lot cases. When you dynamically build your query you will eliminate case statements at all! With dynamic query you will end up with `order by SomeColumn`. You will not have bunch cases and ordering will be just by one column

Comment: is the script running in a stored procedure ?

Comment: @t-clausen.dk Are you saying the CASE would be handled the same way, or the ORDER BY would be?   In other words, is "ORDER BY OneColumn" the same as "ORDER BY NULL, NULL, OneColumn, NULL"?

Comment: no, do you use the row_number to order all rows or only other columns?

Comment: Won't having a single case statement be at least theoretically faster?  With   every one of those a separate statement, it has to evaluate each expression, even though only one of them can be true.

Comment: Is your query inside a procedure?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79023/discussion-on-question-by-user960567-case-when-in-order-by-taking-too-much-time).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to address the first part, `CASE '' WHEN '' THEN CDF.Id END` will be optimised away at compile to just `CDF.Id`, so your first two queries are equivalent. 
At compile time the optimiser knows you want to sort by `CDF.Id` so can generate a plan that utilizes an index on this.

**Short Answer**

Just add the `OPTION (RECOMPILE)` query hint, but this will only help if the column you are sorting on is indexed.

---

**The full answer**

The problem with your latter example is that the optimiser will create a plan based on an unknown value for `@SortExpression`, therefore cannot plan to use an appropriate index, since the sort column is unknown.

I created a simple test DDL:

```
IF OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.T', 'U') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE dbo.T;
CREATE TABLE dbo.T (A INT, B INT, C INT);
INSERT dbo.T (A, B, C)
SELECT  TOP 100000 
        A = ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) % 1000, 
        B = ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) % 1000, 
        C = ABS(CHECKSUM(NEWID())) % 1000
FROM    sys.all_objects AS a 
        CROSS JOIN sys.all_objects AS b;

CREATE INDEX IX_T_A ON dbo.T (A);
CREATE INDEX IX_T_B ON dbo.T (B);
CREATE INDEX IX_T_C ON dbo.T (C);
```

As a control, I ran:

```
SELECT  TOP 100 A, B, C,
        D = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY A)
FROM    dbo.T
ORDER BY D;
```

This gives a plan as such:

[image]

The key here is that the optimiser knows that rather than sort the whole table, it only needs the first 100 rows from the index `IX_T_A`, which is very cheap compared to sorting the table, since the index is already sorted.

This is our optimal plan for a sort on an indexed column. So the aim of the game is to get to this plan while using a variable to define the sort. Just to explain further, I have used `TOP` because it is representative of what (I assume) you are trying to achieve which is to filter for a certain set of records for paging:

```
SELECT  *
FROM    (   SELECT  A, B, C,
                    D = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY A)
            FROM    dbo.T
        ) T
WHERE   D BETWEEN 150 AND 250;
```

[image]

This gives exactly the same plan, it just means internally the index seek starts further into the index. For the rest of the tests I will continue with `TOP` as it is shorter.

As explained above, if I run this with the variable, the query plan cannot use the index scan on `IX_T_A` since it does not know for sure that `A` will be the sort column, so it just uses a plain old table scan, and has to sort the entire table, rather than being able to just sequentially read from a nonclustered index:

```
DECLARE @Sort VARCHAR(10) = 'A';

SELECT  TOP 100 A, B, C,
        D = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY 
                                CASE WHEN @Sort = 'A' THEN A END ASC,
                                CASE WHEN @Sort = '-A' THEN A END DESC,
                                CASE WHEN @Sort = 'B' THEN B END ASC,
                                CASE WHEN @Sort = '-B' THEN B END DESC,
                                CASE WHEN @Sort = 'C' THEN C END ASC,
                                CASE WHEN @Sort = '-C' THEN C END DESC)
FROM    dbo.T
ORDER BY D;
```

Query Plan:

[image]

The only way around this that I can see is to force recompilation at run-time, so that the redundant sorts can be optimised away, and the correct index used:

```
DECLARE @Sort VARCHAR(10) = 'A';
SELECT  TOP 100 A, B, C,
        D = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY 
                                CASE WHEN @Sort = 'A' THEN A END ASC,
                                CASE WHEN @Sort = '-A' THEN A END DESC,
                                CASE WHEN @Sort = 'B' THEN B END ASC,
                                CASE WHEN @Sort = '-B' THEN B END DESC,
                                CASE WHEN @Sort = 'C' THEN C END ASC,
                                CASE WHEN @Sort = '-C' THEN C END DESC)
FROM    dbo.T
ORDER BY D
OPTION (RECOMPILE);
```

Query Plan:

[image]

As you can see, this has reverted to the plan when the sort column was hard coded. You will have an additional cost at compile time, but this should be less than the additional 10s+ you are seeing in run time.

If you sort on a column without an index then it does not matter whether you recompile or not, it will use the same plan.

Comment: OPTION (RECOMPILE) moved from 13-15 secs to 1 sec :) Thanks simply superb.

Answer (score 1):

The only option that I could think of would require indexes on *all* the columns.  I'm not sure if this is really feasible, but you had all such indexes, then the following might perform well:

```
(case when @SortExpression = 'MerchantName'
      then row_number() over (order by MerchantName)
      when @SortExpression = '-MerchantName'
      then row_number() over (order by MerchantName desc)
      . . .
 end)
```

SQL Server is smart enough to use indexes for `row_number()`, when possible.  And, I'm pretty sure index usage is at the root of the performance difference.  It should be smart enough to use indexes even when `row_number()` is an expression in a `case` statement.

Comment: Could simplify it a bit more by making @SortExpression the case i.e: `Case @SortExpression when 'MerchantName' then row_number() over (order by MerchantName) when '-MerchantName'` etc

Comment: This syntax makes it worse :)

Answer (score 1):

I will strongly recommend to use dynamic query here. For example:

```
declare @mainStatement varchar(1000) = 'select * from sometable'
declare @orderingStatement varchar(1000) = ' order by '

if @SortExpression = 'MerchantName' 
   set @orderingStatement = 'M.Name ASC'
else if @SortExpression = '-MerchantName'
   set @orderingStatement = 'M.Name DESC'
else if
   ......


set @mainStatement = @mainStatement + @orderingStatement 
exec(@mainStatement)
```

This way you will end up with query such us:

```
select * from sometable order by M.Name ASC
```

or

```
select * from sometable order by M.Name DESC
```

You will do your best and optimize query as much as possible. The rest is the job of `DBA`. He will add some missing indexes on table`s columns and voilà.